# Overriding paint method?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I was instructed to change the point color in a [RadioButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RadioButtonField.html), that little blue dot that appears on the selected item, as well as the color of a [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) when pressed, to orange. How can I make this?

I already changed the [LabelField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/LabelField.html) color by making a subclass and overriding the paint method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that underneath the hood the radio button is a pair of image files which is why there is not an API to modify aspects of the image such as colour.

My suggestion to you is download the advanced UI classes (these are great to have anyway): http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

Then use the BitmapButtonField or LabelSwitchField with your own radio button images.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't understand how to make a BitmapButtonField work as a radio button, but used a label switch field since they were just 2 values, I'm gonna mark this as the answer since it was very very helpful, but if you can indicate me how to make the BitmapButtonField work as a radio button (for future reference) I would appreciate it :D

Comment: Yes I'm not sure why I mentioned the option of BitmapButtonField, LabelSwitchField is clearly a better choice. But anyway, with BBF you could toggle a boolean within the FieldChangeListener event and call setImage(bitmap) with the bitmap associated to the current boolean state.